# Mousehover over country in leaflet to see its name

Tags: r, leaflet, mousehover, rnaturalearth

I am creating a map of the world:

```
library(leaflet)
library(rnaturalearth)
countries <- rnaturalearth::countries110
mymap <- leaflet(countries)
mymap %>% addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1)
```

Is it possible to either hover over any country to see its name or to click on any country to see its name?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or, even simpler:

```
library(leaflet)
library(rnaturalearth)

countries <- rnaturalearth::countries110
mymap <- leaflet(countries)
mymap %>% addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, 
                      fillOpacity = 1, label = ~name)
```

As long as the data for the labels is part of the data frame to be plotted the `~` notation works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution.
First, create a list of labels using library "htmltools"
Then lapply it under label = . So, the final code is:

```
library(leaflet)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(htmltools)

countries <- rnaturalearth::countries110
mymap <- leaflet(countries)
labs <- as.list(countries$name)
mymap %>% addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, 
                      fillOpacity = 1, label = lapply(labs, HTML))
```